# Mocking in java covering Jar classes

Tags: java, mockito

I have to connect to ldap to fetch entries. I have used Spring Ldap for this. Below is the sample code

```
  ldapTemplate.search(query().attributes(LdapAttributeConstants.ALL).filter(filter.encode()),userProfileContextMapper);
```

Here the user profile context mapper class is internally called by Spring LDAP template

In my test cases i have mocked the above search method as

```
Mockito.when(ldapTemplate.search(Mockito.any(), 
Mockito.any(UserProfileContextMapper.class)))
            .thenReturn(userList);
```

Here I have mocked the search method. I am unable to get coverage for context mapper class. Is there any way I can get coverage for context mapper class as well?

Comment: Sorry, what stopping you to not use Mockito.any(), instead of Mockito.eq(userProfileContextMapper) where userProfileContextMapper - object which should came exatly in your methods call.

Comment: The point of unit testing is not to generate code coverage; the point is to actually test your program. If you're mocking away the call, you're not using the context mapper. So, you should write a separate test for it.